# Не могу добавить запись Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Не могу добавить запись Wordpress**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить?

**Creating default object from empty value  1   wp-admin/includes/post.php:641**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не могу добавить запись Wordpress

Добавить можешь.  Опубликовать - нет.

> Как решить?

Причин может быть несколько и выяснять всё нужно последовательно. К сож, формат SO - это вопрос-ответ и не подразумевает обсуждение и выяснения. С таким вопросами лучше на форумы.

Но..  Первое, что нужно - это убедиться, что есть права на публикацию. По всей видимости это отключено.  см https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Возможно стоит попробовать отключить все плагины, переключится на дефолтную тему.